# Create R binary packages for Linux that can be installed on different machines?

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, binary, package

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, because if it were, then CRAN would have R Linux binary packages.  Why isn't it possible?  We can create Mac and Windows binary versions of R packages, and these tgz/zip files could be installed on different systems.  Why can't we do the same for Linux?

I'm guessing because there are many different distros, and each distro is different.  Is it possible to create binary files for Debian/Ubuntu and RHEL/CentOS?

If it's possible, how do we do it?  Thanks.

Comment: There's a [Download R for Linux](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/) link on the [CRAN homepage](http://cran.r-project.org/)... isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think they're asking why on Linux all packages are installed from source instead of having some sort of binary available.

Comment: @Dason: but binaries _are_ available.  Note all the `r-cran.*.deb` files [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/).  There aren't binaries for every package for every flavor of linux though because that would require a large amount of maintenance.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Well those are at the most 200 of the almost 4000 possible packages.  If you must point somewhere, use Michael's PPA for "cran2deb4ubuntu" on Launchpad, or Don's debian-r.debian.net which should have just about all packages.  Yet the OP asked about _cross-distro_ binaries and as I tried to answer, that would involve magic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Different compiler releases, different libc/libstc++ releases, different "other library" releases, different per-distro release cycles, ...  make it that you just cannot match that goal with dynamic linking.

You can get half-way there as e.g. RStudio does by a) bundling all your depends and b) reflecting subsets as they do for Debian/Ubuntu and RH/FC/CentOS.   But with a) the tarballs would get massive, as they would with static linking.

In short: you can't on Linux. So back to sources it is.

Comment: So there are binary packages for Mac and Windows because the R core uses a single compiler to build R on each platform (Xcode and MinGW), and so packages are built the same way and hence can be transferred from machine to machine?  Thanks Dirk.

Comment: @Dirk We're using Docker to deploy Shiny apps using rocker/shiny (`debian:testing`).  Build times are long because of package compilation.  Given the target Linux system is always the same, is there any way of creating our own CRAN mirror  with precompiled packages for our specific Linux version.  Or is there a similar solution which would achieve the same goal? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can.  There used to be a service for that (google "cran2deb"), and we are trying to rebuild one.  It won't be ready "soon" though.  But you can very much proxy it locally.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel is there a place where we can follow progress on the effort you mention above?

Comment: @KenWilliams Check out https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ , maintainer is Dirk Eddelbuettel himself (found September 2022)

Comment: See https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/ for an even more extensive coverage of all of CRAN.