# Factors that contribute to an R binary package

Tags: r, package, binaryfiles

Binary packages are generally not available for Linux (see discussion at [Create R binary packages for Linux that can be installed on different machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871394/169947), for example).

However, this can often lead to very long build times when doing Continuous Integration testing.  After many years of just waiting for those long builds, I would like to build binary packages from source, then cache those binaries for reinstallation later in future builds.

The question is what factors should go into the cache key - what should be considered "the same platform" so that a binary package can (relatively) safely be pulled from the cache and installed.  I can think of:

- Everything in `R.version` (or maybe just the entries `platform`, `major`, and `minor`)
- Everything in the output of `R CMD config --all`
- Value of `R.home()`

Anything else I'm missing?

My thought is to dump all this info into a file, compute an `md5` or `shasum` on it, and use that as the cache key.

I'm aware of some similar efforts, but nothing that fits the bill in a general way:

- https://github.com/r-lib/crancache (e.g. https://github.com/r-lib/crancache/issues/20)
- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't `R.home()` provide about the same useful information as `R.version`? Either way, though I don't know how to get a local CRAN repo (and `tools::write_PACKAGES`) to recognize linux binaries (error: `'arg' should be one of “source”, “mac.binary”, “win.binary”`), isn't the analogous directory structure sufficient? For instance, I might expect: `.../bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES` (if generated correctly).

Comment: @r2evans there's definitely overlap, but `R.home()` doesn't include any info about what kind of architecture you're on (the `platform` key of `R.version`.